# Should I use multiple classes for bloc states or one class with multiple constructors?

Tags: flutter, oop, dart, bloc

I have started learning bloc recently and I noticed some tutorials use multiple classes for states and others just use one class with multiple named constructors.

Example for multiple classes:

```
abstract class ProductsState {}

class ProductsInitial extends ProductsState {}

class ProductsLoading extends ProductsState {}

class ProductsSuccess extends ProductsState {
  final List<Products> products;

  ProductsSuccess(this.products);
}

class ProductsError extends ProductsState {
  final String error;

  ProductsError(this.error);
}
```

Example for multiple constructors:

```
enum AuthenticationStates {
  initial,
  success,
  error,
}

class AuthenticationState {
  final AuthenticationStates state;
  final Authentication model;
  final String msg;

  const AuthenticationState._(
      {this.state = AuthenticationStates.initial,
      this.model,
      this.msg = ''});

  const AuthenticationState.initial() : this._();

  const AuthenticationState.success(Authentication mdl)
      : this._(model: mdl, state: AuthenticationStates.success);

  const AuthenticationState.error(String m)
      : this._(state: AuthenticationStates.error, msg: m);
}
```

Which one is better to use?

Comment: Just for me the first one is better as you do not have to make some fields nullable for other states. I will advice you to check the freezed library for this case its much better for handling multiple states (https://pub.dev/packages/freezed).

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I use the first way since different state types are clear, you can later build your UI based on that e.g. `if (state is ProductsLoading) { show loader }`.

You can also generate such classes by using the freezed package (https://pub.dev/packages/freezed). When using it, you would define a single class with different factory constructors (similar to your second option), but the generated code would support the first option you've defined, e.g.:

```
@freezed
class Union with _$Union {
  const factory Union(int value) = Data;
  const factory Union.loading() = Loading;
  const factory Union.error([String message]) = ErrorDetails;
}
```

Later, in the UI layer, you could use helper methods like map/maybeMap/when/maybeWhen to build the corresponding view based on state, e.g.:

```
var union = Union(42);

print(
  union.when(
    (int value) => 'Data $data',
    loading: () => 'loading',
    error: (String? message) => 'Error: $message',
  ),
); // Data 42
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asking myself the same question.

"The moment you check the concrete type of an instance in your logic, know you're not using polymorphism correctly." - Back in the university.

In the documentation of BloC they use one class with enum in all examples(or extra status class),
the enum will be composed of something similar to SUCCESS FAILURE etc.

Check the PostState mentioned in BloC documentation as example:
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterinfinitelisttutorial?id=post-states

Nevertheless, the multiple sub-classes for state is a commonly used practice among flutter devs. It looks wrong for me, but who knows...